# How to start Firefox in hidden mode from C#?

Tags: c#, .net, firefox

how can I start Firefox as hidden application in my C# application?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "hidden mode"?

Answer (score 1):

The ProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow property only applies to console mode apps.  A regular GUI app requires a window to be functional.  It is supposed to observe the ProcessStartInfo.WindowStyle property but not all GUI apps are well behaved, particularly when you ask for ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden.  Which presents a user interface problem, can't get the window activated when it is hidden.

A minimized window is usually the best you can get, with a taskbar button.

Answer (score 0):

I think. You are asking how to run a program without displaying in Task manager. ?? if its true, then You Can Set ShowInTaskBar Property to false of that Form.  if not then can u explain what "Hidden Mode" means ?  so that it is easy to solve the problem

```
Form.ShowInTaskBar=false;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showintaskbar.aspx